# onClick method runs setState multiple times in a row, negating intended purpose

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to have my onClick method `handleClick` set the state of the `active` and `groupCardInfo` properties. `active` in particular is a boolean, and I'm using this bool value to determine whether a side menu item should be expanded or not.

**SideMenuContainer** component that calls `handleClick`:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.active == true){
      return (
        <ParentContainer>
          <p onClick={this.props.handleClick(this.props.properties)}>{this.props.parentName}</p>        
          <NestedContainer>
            {this.props.properties.map(propertyElement => {
              return (
                <NestedProperty onClick={() => { this.props.changeInfoList(propertyElement.name, propertyElement.data_type, propertyElement.app_keys)}} >
                  {propertyElement.name}
                </NestedProperty>
              );
            })}
          </NestedContainer>
        </ParentContainer>
      );    
    }
```

The issue is that clicking that `<p>` results in `handleClick` running multiple times. so rather than toggling the `active` value from false to true, it toggles it back and forth multiple times so that it goes from false back to false again.

What's incorrect with the way I'm structuring this method in the parent `App.js` that's causing this?:

```
  handleClick(properties){
    console.log("toggle click!")
    // this.setState({active : !this.state.active});

    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active,
      groupedCardInfo: properties
    })

    console.log("the active state is now set to: " + this.state.active)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are invoking the function in event handler. The first time `render` runs it will execute your event handler. You can do this like your other `onClick` handler:

```
<p onClick={() => { this.props.handleClick(this.props.properties) }}>{this.props.parentName}</p>
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
<p onClick={this.props.handleClick}>{this.props.parentName}</p>
```

But then you would have to change how you reference `properties` in your click handler. Like this:

```
handleClick(){
    const properties = this.props.properties

    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active,
      groupedCardInfo: properties
    })

    console.log("the active state is now set to: " + this.state.active)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using arrow function, like you did on the other `onClick`:

```
<p onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.properties)}>
```

Calling `this.props.handleClick...` while rendering, invokes it.
Then, setting the state, makes the component to re render.